# A finite simple group with $\pi (G)\subseteq \pi (p^{2}-1)$

Tags: finite-groups

Let $\pi (k)$ be the set of prime divisors of $k$ and let $\pi (G)=\pi (|G|)$. Let $G$ be finite simple group with $\pi (G)\subseteq \pi (p^{2}-1)$,
where $p$ is prime.

I would like to know is there any classifications for group $G$?

Comment: Do you mean for *any* prime $p$ or a *specific* prime $p$?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: $p$ is prime but not Mersenne or Fermat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$G$ could be any finite simple group. For any positive integer $n$, there exists a prime $p$ congruent to $1$ mod $n$ by Dirichlet's theorem. And of course if $p \equiv 1 \pmod n$, then every divisor of $n$ is a divisor of $p-1$ and hence of $p^2-1$.

Comment: Do you think you can help [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312159/free-groups-and-relations-showing-that-g-simeq-fg3-n-for-n-the-normal)?